# Write Database table to txt file PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I need some help with this problem.

I'm work with laravel, and I got the select which look like this:

```
$table = Onlineszallas::all()->toArray();
```

I wanna write this query to a TXT file with latin2 file charset, every row in the table, in new line,  strings separated by ; and every row end with;

I tried the `fputcsv()` method but if I open the txt file I found some string which contain space between to **apostrophe** like the name row.
"George Michael"

I need some help with `file_put_contents()` or any other method which can solve my problem!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Storage`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#storing-files) facade. Create a file:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
Storage::put('file.txt', $contents);
```

Add text content to a file:

```
Storage::append('file.txt', $someOtherContent);
```

But I would recomment you to store data as JSON:

```
$table = Onlineszallas::all()->toJson();
```

In this case you'll be able to easily import the data in any system.

Comment: And how can I make a foreach loop with this query? Because I don't know how to fetch an array in laravel, and why better to store data in JSON?